# How do I play arbitrary MIDI notes with javascript?

Tags: javascript, midi

To clarify: I don't want to generate a MIDI file nor do I want to play a MIDI file, I wish to play MIDI notes on the fly.

I tried using https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js as the MIDI library, and it works somewhat.

I am able to play notes by calling `MIDI.noteOn(0,midiNumber,100);`. However, this plays a note for a couple seconds and then tapers off even if I never call `MIDI.noteOff`.

I don't believe this is how MIDI is intended to work. I wish to be able to call noteOn and have a note play and sustain until noteOff is called.

Intended browsers: modern firefox/chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bug your version of MIDI.js:

```
var playChannel = function (id) {
    var note = notes[id];
    if (!note) return;
    var nid = (channel_nid + 1) % channels.length;
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    var audio = channels[nid];
    channel_map[note.id] = audio;
    audio.src = MIDI.Soundfont[note.id];
    audio.volume = volume;
    audio.play();
    channel_nid = nid;
};
```

As you can see `playChannel` will load a given note and play it. Since there is no autoloop attribute it won't repeat, so the call of `noteOff` isn't necessary. You could fix this yourself if you set the `audio` element to auto-loop.

Comment: Wow. Nice to have spotted a bug. +1, though don't you want to make a pull request?

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm currently not at my PC and I'm still not used to the github interface (I prefer bitbucket). However, I believe some applications use this bug and would stop to work, as they didn't use `noteOff` (could be possible after all). Maybe in ~11h (21:00 UTC+1).

Comment: Ah, I noticed this bug while reading the code but wasn't too sure what the fix was. Seeing as some of the implementations don't even have any code in noteOff() this bug might actually be an intended design flaw. I agree with your qualms against modifying the code for legacy purposes. You should make a fork request instead. For now I'll just monkey patch this and see if it works.

Comment: @RazorStorm: After all it is just an assumption. The bug _could_ be in this very function, however, since the whole project isn't very well documentated it is hard to get it right without actually testing it (can't do that at the moment :/).

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/ provides various sound generators for which noteOn and noteOff can be called.

Answer (score 2):

This is right behavour. You need a better samples library to play long sounds.

See [church organ example](https://surikov.github.io/midi-sounds-react-examples/examples/midi-sounds-example10/build/) of endless sound.

this exanple uses [WebAudioFont](https://github.com/surikov/webaudiofont) to play more then 1500 instruments and drums. This lib supports ADSR, reverberation and loop points.

Answer (score 1):

Google for Web MIDI API.
It is not implemented in all browsers yet, but there is a polyfill by Chris Wilson at GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Different instruments behave differently. A piano has an "intrinsic" note off, but an organ doesn't.

Also, `noteOn` and `noteOff` depend on the implementation. `modcu.be` in the HTML5 implementation plays a OGG file for each note, and it doesn't care of `noteOff` at all. When the OGG ends, the sound stops. And `autoloop` wouldn't help for a piano in this case.